# Google App Engine long process that needs to return to consumer

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, httprequest, synchronization, polling

I am trying to use Google App Engine as a mediator between the mobile platform and a popular cloud storage service. The mobile app tells app engine what parts of a particular file it wants from the cloud storage, app engine should then fetch that file data, processes it and extracts the requested parts to send back to the mobile app. Yes it has to be set up this way, the mobile os is unable to read files of this particular format, but app engine can, and this particular cloud storage is integrated with a required desktop software.

The issue: processing the file and extracting the data exceeds the 60 second response limit and the Task Queue cannot return data back to the originally requesting mobile app. in most cases, the data would be ready to return in 1-3 minutes. I realize that the Channel Api could allow me to receive real-time messages via a web view as to when the data is ready, but this api is very expensive since I would need to allow for thousands of connections a day and each user has to have their own channel per the docs. Should I look in to polling (outside the channel api)? What design models, methods or even other services should I look in to (I have been using gae because of its ease of use, automatic scaling and security; I'm a one man show).

The product relies on a capability that only exists in Java to process the data. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at google cloud messaging for android and ios push system whichever mobile os?

Comment: That's a pretty cool ability, but I need to be guaranteed that the app will receive the message, but using push notifications on iOS can Easily be rejected.

Comment: For any who land here - for me this became an issue of the efficiency of my app. This is not an answer because it does not address the original issue of handling long tasks in GAE with minimal cost: in my app I was turning hundreds if not thousands of Map<String,Object> entity representations into POJOs for processing, which worked ok when the app was on the desktop platform. Now I simply return the JSONfied Map objects to the mobile platform and process them there = MUCH faster. So tip for others: find caveats for efficiency in GAE apps (or any app) to maximize savings

Answer (score 0):

You could return a transaction id to the client, and then let the client periodically ping your server with that id to see if the long process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Appengine 'Backend' instances do not have the 60 seconds limit. You can see the comparison between normal frontend instance and backend instance here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/

Comment: Yes, nor does the Task Queue (currently has a limit of 10 minutes). But the problem is that I need to return data back to the requesting consumer as soon as the data is available, in the most efficient way, primarily concerning cost.